# First Webview was working , but button are not clicking and not showing photos

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

i created a webview for my site , the page is hosted in my server, it works fine when inspecting element with mobile phone setting , but when the same page is loaded to the webview in android , the button when clicks does nothing and images are not loading

i added the lines

```
 val mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings()
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) 
        mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false)
        mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true)
        mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true)
```

MainAcitvity

```
package com.example.student.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.webkit.WebSettings



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mWebView: WebView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        mWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview);
        val mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings()
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) 
        mWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
        mWebSettings.setSupportZoom(false)
        mWebSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true)
        mWebSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true)
        mWebView!!.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean{
                view?.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }
        }
        mWebView!!.loadUrl("https://qiwi.io/")
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the line

```
val mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings()
```

Comment: Attach your error

Answer (score 0):

try following...

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)
```

**Kotlin**

```
webView.settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
```

Comment: but i am getting error in the line val mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings()